# GetCellValue return Nodata

Tags: arcpy

A have a raster image in .tif format (WGS 1984). I want to retrieve the cell value when input the pixel row and column. I found the most suitable tool
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-cell-value.htm

I tried the following  code

```
result = arcpy.GetCellValue_management ("G:/06_DROUGHT_RISK/VCI/GeoTif/001_2001.tif", "309 320")
```

Even though it seems quite straightforward, every time i try to return cell value, I get `NoData` as the output

I also looked into the following link
https://community.esri.com/thread/69009

However I could not find the solution from given answers as well